# How do I add certain values from a json file to a python for loop and listbox?

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I want to make a for loop that will add "Network Name, Network IP, Subnet, Inter Devs, and Hosts" to a label then take the "Usable IPs" and put them into a list box below the label. Does anyone know how I can do this?

I have put my json file and for loop below.

JSON:

```
{
  "networks": [
    {
      "Network Name": "wha",
      "Network IP": "10.0.1.0",
      "Subnet": "255.255.255.240",
      "Usable IPs": [
        "10.0.1.1",
        "10.0.1.2",
        "10.0.1.3",
        "10.0.1.4",
        "10.0.1.5",
        "10.0.1.6",
        "10.0.1.7",
        "10.0.1.8",
        "10.0.1.9",
        "10.0.1.10"
      ],
      "Intermediary Devices": "1",
      "Hosts": "9"
    },
    {
      "Network Name": "newnet",
      "Network IP": "192.168.0.0",
      "Subnet": "255.255.255.240",
      "Usable IPs": [
        "192.168.0.1",
        "192.168.0.2",
        "192.168.0.3",
        "192.168.0.4",
        "192.168.0.5",
        "192.168.0.6",
        "192.168.0.7",
        "192.168.0.8",
        "192.168.0.9",
        "192.168.0.10"
      ],
      "Intermediary Devices": "2",
      "Hosts": "8"
    },
    {
      "Network Name": "myNet",
      "Network IP": "192.168.0.12",
      "Subnet": "255.255.255.0",
      "Usable IPs": [
        "192.168.0.13",
        "192.168.0.14",
        "192.168.0.15",
        "192.168.0.16",
        "192.168.0.17",
        "192.168.0.18",
        "192.168.0.19",
        "192.168.0.20"
      ],
      "Intermediary Devices": "10",
      "Hosts": "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

Python:

```
import json
import ctypes
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

class NetAppHomePG:


    def __init__(self):

        self.win = Tk()
        self.win.geometry("3800x2000")
        self.win.title("NetApp")

        self.TabsFrame = Frame(self.win)


        self.r=0
        self.c=1

        self.TabsFrame.grid(sticky=W)
        self.MyNetsCanvas = Canvas(self.TabsFrame, height=1500, width=2500)
        self.MyNetsCanvas.grid(row=0, rowspan=3, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=200)
        self.MyNetsFrame = Frame(self.MyNetsCanvas, height=10000, width=500)
        self.MyNetsCanvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.MyNetsFrame, anchor=NW)

        with open("user.json") as f:
            self.data = json.load(f)
            self.temp = self.data['networks']
            
        for self.network in self.data['networks']:
            self.MyNets = Frame(self.MyNetsFrame)
            self.MyNets.grid(row=self.r, column=self.c, pady=40)
            if (self.c + 1) % 2 == 0:
                self.r += 1
                self.c = 1
            else:
                self.c += 1
            for key, value in self.network.items():
                Label(self.MyNets, text=f'{key}: {value}', anchor="w", bg="white", fg="black", font=("Roboto", 14), width=100).grid(padx=150)

        self.win.mainloop()

NetAppHomePG()
```

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: It would help if you explicitly describe the issue you run into and focus the example on the issue. Also, it looks like you save the network data to `self.temp` but never use that value. However, the main issue is you are not seeing a result because you have not started tkinter.

Comment: my bad I forgot to add that part into the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
try:
    with open('user.json') as json_file:
        json_response = json.load(json_file)
        for network in json_response.get('networks', ''):
            network_name = network.get('Network Name', '')
            network_ip = network.get('Network IP', '')
            subnet = network.get('Subnet', '')
            intermediary_devices = network.get('Intermediary Devices', '')
            hosts = network.get('Hosts', '')
            for usable_ip in network.get('Usable IPs', []):
                print(usable_ip)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also Stack Overflow's [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.

Comment: An explanation of how and why your code works and addresses the question would be ideal. Remember, you are leaving solutions not just for the original asker but for future users, so providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized, but not started `tkinter`. The function to start tkinter is `mainloop()`, so you need to call `self.win.mainloop()` at the end of your `__init__`.

You will also need to create an instance of the class you created. So add `NetAppHomePG()` to the end of your program.